# MVC + Datatables error depending from number of table rows

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have an MVC project which connects (through the controller) to MS SQL Server, gets the dataset, and shows it on the DataTables using following construction:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        // Call table data from controller action
        $.getJSON("/Home/MyAction", { DateShow: "@ViewBag.TblCurrentDate" },
        function (json) {

            // Append each row to html table
            var tr;
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i]["Column Name 1"] + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i]["Column Name 2"] + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i]["Column Name 3"] + "</td>");
...
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i]["Column Name 20"] + "</td>");

                $('#MyTable').append(tr);
            }

            // Set table name and apply datetable settings
            var dt_olktable = $('#MyTable').DataTable()
    });
});
```

So if I get from SQL a dataset of 1500 row and 20 columns, it works perfect (1-2 secs). If I have 2000 rows and more, with 20 columns, I see an "Error Page" in Events section of VS2015 Diagnostoc Tools - just after the Event "GET "/Home/MyAction". I've tryed to set up a breakpoint on c# controller class. The controller have sucessfully get dataset, put it into json and return json to jquery code which is shown before. Also, there are not errors in Chrome Dev Tools panel. All i know: when I put breakpoint to

```
var tr;
```

row, the breakpoint is never fired, so something happens just near

```
$.getJSON("/Home/MyAction", { DateShow: "@ViewBag.TblCurrentDate" },
            function (json) {
```

rows.

If I reduce number of data (f.e. 1500 rows, 20 columns), all works! Maybe, 2000 rows * 20 columns is too much for DataTables using client-side-processing? Or maybe there is something like overflow in

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
```

row?

Comment: When debugging in the browser's debugging tools, what is the server's response to that AJAX request?  If it's an "error page", what is the error?

Comment: There is no error page or something like it. The answer below explains why.

Comment: The answer below is misleading in that regard.  The debugging tools in your browser can show you the server’s response to the AJAX request.  Have you tried any such debugging?  The question indicates that a breakpoint inside the success callback isn’t reached, so it seems the expected response doesn’t come back from the server.  So what *does* come back from the server?

Comment: I've tried Crome Dev tools, and there was nothing shown. The only place i see that something goes wrong (except not finished web page in browser) is Visual Studio (see my question).

Comment: *"there was nothing shown"* - Specifically what did you look at?  What do you mean by "nothing shown"?  Was the server's response an empty page?  What was the HTTP status code for the response?  If the response content doesn't contain anything helpful, is the Web.config set to not display errors?  What happens if you change that?

Comment: I look everything: browser, logs, dev tool. There is no http status code, the page have loaded, but without table data from dataset. There was no error except VS. Webconfig is of course ok.

Comment: *"There is no http status code"* - Every HTTP response has a status code.  Is there no response at all?  Does the AJAX request just wait indefinitely?  Is the AJAX request even made?  It's sounding like you just don't know *how* to debug this.  Which we can help with, but we need to be aware of that because it changes the nature of the question being asked.  We need to be able to determine what specifically is failing, and insisting that you've already "looked at everything" doesn't really accomplish that.

Comment: Strange thing... I restarted a project once again and now can see the error (500). It was a problem with maxJsonLength which I've fixed yet. I ask you to post your last comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The `$.getJSON()` function only has the `success` callback. It doesn't have the `fail` callback, so if there is any exception, it will usually fail silently and you will not be able to see the error even in debug.

Change it to `$ajax()`, provide a function for the `fail` callback, place a breakpoint in it, and you'll see the error.